# ¿Cómo agregar y utilizar librerías .aar en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estoy haciendo una aplicación y voy a utilizar una ***librería***, pero no sé en que carpeta debo de agregar el AAR o de que forma agregarlo al proyecto para poder utilizarlo en la aplicación.

Estoy utilizando **Android Studio 3.0**. Me podrían orientar. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente los archivos .aar o [Android Archive Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents) a diferencia de los .jar  se diferencian de estos ya que contienen recursos y un archivo androidmanifest.xml.

Anteriormente creabas un directorio `/libs` agregabas ahí las library y definías el registro de la misma en el archivo `build.gradle`

**Si ahora usas Android Studio 3.0, la forma adecuada de agregar un .AAR o .JAR a tu proyecto es precisamente la indicada por la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents):**

> 1. Agrega la biblioteca a tu proyecto de dos maneras (si creaste el módulo de biblioteca dentro del mismo proyecto, ya estará allí y
>      podrás omitir este paso):
>
> Agrega el archivo AAR compilado (o JAR):
>
> - Haz clic en **File** > **New Module**.
> - Haz clic en **Import .JAR/.AAR Package** y luego en **Next**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> - Ingresa la ubicación del archivo AAR o JAR y luego haz clic en Finish
>
> Importa el módulo de biblioteca a tu proyecto:
>
> - Haz clic en **File** > **New** > **Import Module**.
> - Ingresa la ubicación del directorio del módulo de biblioteca y luego haz clic en Finish.
>
> El módulo de biblioteca se copia a tu proyecto, para que realmente
>   puedas editar el código de biblioteca. Si deseas mantener una única
>   versión del código de biblioteca, probablemente esto no sea lo que
>   buscas y, como alternativa, debes importar el archivo AAR compilado
>   como se describe anteriormente.
>
> 2. Asegura que la biblioteca se ubique en la parte superior de tu archivo `settings.gradle`, como se muestra aquí para una biblioteca
>      llamada “my-library-module”:
>
>    `include ':app', ':my-library-module'`
> 3. Abre el archivo `build.gradle` del módulo de la app y agrega una línea nueva al bloque de dependencies como se muestra en el siguiente
>      fragmento:
>
> `dependencies {`
>       `compile project(":my-library-module") }`
>
> 4. Haz clic en **Sync Project with Gradle Files** para sincronizar el proyecto con los archivos gradle.

Answer (score 1):

- Una vez situado en tu proyecto Android Studio, crea la carpeta **“libs”** a la altura de build y src.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Una vez hayas creado esta carpeta, ya podrás añadir todos los .jar que quieras (y seguir el procedimiento que vemos a continuación para todas las librerías). Pero esto no termina aquí, porque el siguiente paso es muy importante, necesitas añadir las dependencias a Build.gradle (Module:app).
- En este ejemplo añadimos la librería **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**. Para ello, añadimos el siguiente código en `Build.gradle`, en `dependencies()`. Se hace igual para cualquier librería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]